# ASIFormDataRequest post type

Tags: web-services, ios5, asiformdatarequest

I need to send RestFul Web Service Request with post type ,post data format is like as below {"Request":"parameters".... }and binary data with same request.Is it possible with ios if possible means explain please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using the ASIHttpRequest library anymore because it's not getting any updates from the developer , as to how to create a post http request here's an example

```
NSString *url = @"your webservice base url";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *param2 = ...//
NSData *binaryData = .... //initilize the binary data you want to send
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param1=%@&param2=%@",binartData,param2];



[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [bodyString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];//or set the type of encoding agreed with your webservice

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseString;
if ( responseData && !error){
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

Comment: thanks ...but i need to send json data as a parameter{"parameters"=...} and binary data of image to server

Comment: json objects are just strings.. you can save the JSON data in NSString object and send it as one parameter.